# How to resolve an ambiguous reference caused by a conflicting identifier from inline namespace

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace N1
{
    int x = 2;
}

int x = 1;

int main()
{
    std::cout << N1::x;
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

This obivously gives me error on `std::cout << x;`

> reference to x is ambiguous.

`::x` also does not work.

**I understand why it happens, but how can I solve this problem without renaming or removing variables or namespaces? Or it is the only solution?**

Comment: Don't declare the second `x` in the global namespace.

Comment: @KerrekSB I edited the question. Of course I can do this, but I wonder if there are another solutions.

Comment: This seems like a "Doctor it hurts" kind of situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Inline namespace scoped variables have *static [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (internal linking)*. So</del> declaring

```
extern int x;
```

just before displaying `x` will do it for you
[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ad316e1231bd678).
<del>This way, the `N1::x` won't be considered during name lookup, as it has static storage duration and internal linking.</del>

It's not entirely clear why the code works, so I follow up with a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877510/do-inline-namespace-variables-have-static-storage-duration).

Comment: I realized that although the solution I proposed works, the explanation may not be entirely correct. In other words, I don't find anything that specifies that inline namespace variables have static storage duration.

Comment: Follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877510/do-inline-namespace-variables-have-static-storage-duration