# Do inline namespace variables have internal linkage? If not, why does the code below work?

Tags: c++, c++11, linkage

This question is directly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33876647/3093378). Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

inline namespace N1
{
    int x = 42;
}
int x = 10;

int main()
{
    extern int x;
    std::cout << x; // displays 10
}
```

It displays `10`. If I remove the `extern int x;` declaration then we get an ambiguity compiler time error

> error: reference to 'x' is ambiguous

Question: why does the code work with the `extern int x` declaration work, and why does it stop working when I remove it? Is it because inline namespace variables have internal linkage?

Comment: They don't have internal linkage, unless enclosed by an unnamed namespace. Are you confusing inline and unnamed?

Comment: @T.C. No, I don't confuse them. I knew that unnamed namespaces have internal linkage.

Comment: You should probably rephrase the question to "why does it work", since you're probably more interested in that than in the strictly boolean answer to whether inline namespace variables actually have static storage or internal linkage (which is what the current answers address).

Comment: OK, now you are confusing static storage duration and internal linkage.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, edited.

Comment: This particular lookup is somewhat underspecified. Compare [CWG1839](http://wg21.link/CWG1839).

Comment: @T.C. is this exact case underspecified? [basic.link]/6 says that `extern int x;` matches an object declared in the innermost enclosing scope only, so it can only match `x=10` here.  The definition of inline namespaces doesn't contain anything to contradict this; it lists a bunch of ways that `N1::x` can be referred to as `x` but none of them match `extern int x;`

Comment: I would answer this question by saying that `N1::x` has external linkage, but block-scope `extern int x;` does not match names declared in a namespace other than the innermost enclosing namespace , even if said namespace is `inline`

Comment: @M.M I'm inclined to agree w/r/t the current wording of the standard. I'm less sure as to the intent (since inline namespaces are designed to be transparent for most purposes).

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no provision in [basic.link] that would cause `x` to have internal linkage. Specifically, "All other namespaces have external linkage.", and "other" refers to "not unnamed". Perhaps you were thinking of *unnamed namespaces*?

Comment: I know thats not specifically what OP asked, but why then does adding extern fix the ambiguity?

Comment: @Borgleader: Same reason that `extern` selects the outermost name in `int x; { int x; { int x; { int x; { extern int x; x = 10; } } } }`?

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the code works because to avoid breaking existing C code, `extern int x;` has to work the same way in did in C, in other words creating a local `extern` to a global namespace (that's all we had in C) variable. Then when you use it later the locally declared extern removes any possible ambiguity.

Comment: It refers to the innermost enclosing namespace, not the global namespace. E.g. `int x = 10; namespace S { int x = 20; void f() { extern int x; printf("%d\n", x);} } int main() { S::f(); }` prints `20`